# Two led voltage indicator

Tags: voltage, transistors, led, zener

I need a schematic of voltage indicator with two NPN transistors and two Zener diodes. When the input is 9V one led is lighting, the other when the input is 12V.
This is my progress, but I'm not sure if it's gonna work. I don't know to calculate the values of components.
[image]

Comment: Ok. What have you tried so far in order to find such a schematic?

Comment: Given that you have specified your parts list this sounds like homework with no attempt at a solution. This is a question and answer site and you have not asked a question. "Give me a circuit ..." is not a question.

Comment: I posted my circuit

Comment: It looks like you're using LTspice so what happens when you run a simulation?

Comment: Doesn't work, none of the diodes.

Comment: How You know that this doesn't work? In Ltspice leds will not "light up" - measure current throught them.

Comment: You don't appear to have assigned values to R1 and R4. I don't know what the simulator will do in that case.

Comment: One thing that does not work, as I found out the hard way recently in incorrectly answering a question with a similarly ill-conceived circuit, is relying on a zener or 0.7V diode drop if there isn't sufficient current through the diode. In particular, the current through your diodes is restricted by transistor base current which is tiny, far less than required to get the desired drop. You need to make sure at least several mA flow through a diode/zener in order to depend on its nominal voltage drop.

Comment: @kubaM How accurate does this need to be? How repeatable (from circuit instance to different circuit instance with different parts) does this need to be?

Comment: You could do it with a LM358 or some cheap opamp, a few resistors and LEDs. I would you go back to ground zero. Does the transistor part look correct? Should you be using PNP transistors, just a few things to check out. This not intended as an answer but some homework for  you.

Comment: I figured the solution out with my profesor, I can post the schematic later, but I built it and it works.